# Set route line between two point (start point and end point) in Skobbler Map Android

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I have two `AutoCompleteTextView` for start point and end point. At `onCreate()` method,for start point, i use :

```
currentText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                currentText.setText(startingPointSearchAdapter.getPlaceList().get(i).getName());
                Place startPointPlace = startingPointSearchAdapter.getPlaceList().get(i);
                if (mapView != null) {
                    CustomSKAnnotation skAnnotation = new CustomSKAnnotation(new Random().nextInt(),startPointPlace.getName());
                    skAnnotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_BLUE);
                    skAnnotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(startPointPlace.getLongitude(), startPointPlace.getLatitude()));
                    mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
                    mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                }
            }
        });
```

and for end point, i use :

```
destinationText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            destinationText.setText(destinationPointSearchAdapter.getPlaceList().get(i).getName());
            Place destinationPointPlace = destinationPointSearchAdapter.getPlaceList().get(i);
            if (mapView != null) {
                CustomSKAnnotation skAnnotation = new CustomSKAnnotation(new Random().nextInt(),destinationPointPlace.getName());
                skAnnotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_RED);
                skAnnotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(destinationPointPlace.getLongitude(), destinationPointPlace.getLatitude()));
                mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
                mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have method for `route` between two point :

```
private void showRoute() {
    SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
    route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate());
    route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate());
    route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
    route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
    route.setRouteExposed(true);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
    SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
}
```

Here, 

        `route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate());
        route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate());`

How do i set the start point coordinate and destination point coordinate, so that i draw the route ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question right you just need to do:

```
route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(startPointPlace.getLongitude(), 
    startPointPlace.getLatitude()));

route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(destinationPointPlace.getLongitude(),
    destinationPointPlace.getLatitude()));
```